# Parse a properties file with groovy

Tags: parsing, properties, groovy

I'm trying to extract the username and password from a properties file containing :

```
#Fri May 31 09:33:22 CEST 2013 
password=user40_31-05-2013 
username=user40_31-05-2013


File propertiesFile = new File('testdata.properties')
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(propertiesFile.toURL())
println(config.username)
```

I'm having this error:

> expecting '!', found 'F' @ 
>   line 1, column 2.    #Fri May 31 09:33:22 CEST 2013
>       ^
>
> 1 error

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can save having to close the stream yourself with the more idiomatic:

```
def props = new Properties()
new File("foo.properties").withInputStream { s ->
  props.load(s) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm being an idiot here, but isn't the larger problem that he's using a shell-style comment character (#) instead of a groovy comment (// or /* ... */)?

His error message is because # at the beginning of a unix script should be followed by ! and then the path to an interpreter. (Something like #!/bin/sed)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) type:

```
def props = new Properties()
def stream = new FileInputStream("foo.properties")
try {
  props.load(stream)
} finally {
  stream.close()
}
System.out.println(props)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem and answers. All answers seems to be correct to me, but no one answers the root cause.

[ConfigSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html) is a simple class, which only has few methods. The most important method are named `parse`. There is only one parse method that is applicable to properties. the others are for Groovy script file.

[image: javadoc]

So based on the document, you are trying to read configuration from a Groovy script, not properties file. That's the reason why it complain as following message. Because Groovy script may declare shebang likes `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` at the beginning of file.

```
expecting '!', found 'F' @ line 1, column 2. #Fri May 31 09:33:22 CEST 2013 ^

1 error
```

Here is the modification based on your code to fix the problem

```
    Properties props = new Properties()
    new File('testdata.properties').withInputStream { props.load(it) }
    def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)
    println config.username
```