# How can I access the values in application.properties of a Grails plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm able to get values from the application's application.properties using `grailsApplication.metadata[key]`, but I'm having a hard time getting the same for a loaded Grails plugin.

I've tried `grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins` but the instances in that list don't contain the values from the plugins' applications.properties files.

I've also tried `GrailsPluginUtils.getMetadataForPlugin(pluginName)`, but that doesn't return the values from applications.properties either. (In fact, I usually get null.)

Is there a way to get to these values at runtime?

Comment: Which value from plugin's `application.properties` are you looking for to use in the app?

Comment: A custom value, say `app.foo="bar"`, and I'd like to be able to get `metadata['foo']`.

Comment: Why is a plugin putting custom values in `application.properties`?

Answer (score 2):

@Michael answer can be made nicer indeed. Add a `def grailsApplication` where needed, then access your property `app.myprp` using something like `${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.myprp'}`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't like this as an answer, so I'm hoping that someone will still point me in the right direction.

Because I can't find a way to get to the plugin metadata, I'm reading the plugin `application.properties` files manually (following https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872275/489597):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginUtils

GrailsPluginUtils.getPluginDirectories().collect {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    File propertiesFile = new File("${it.getPath()}/application.properties")
    propertiesFile.withInputStream {
        properties.load(it)
    }
    properties
}
```

It's been pointed out to me that this won't work in a packaged WAR, because the application.properties files won't be present unless perhaps they're copied into WEB-INF.