# Grails: Initialize variable using Configuration file

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration, initialization

I just wanted to know that is it possible to set the value of a variable in Grails controller from the configuration file like config.groovy or some other configuration file?

For instance , my controller is as follows:

```
class WebsiteController {
    def show(){
        String user_name = "value to be fetched from configuration file"
    }
}
```

Here, I want to set the value of user_name from the configuration file. I have no idea how to do this.
I have been given this requirement by my senior. I searched online but couldn't find anything relevant. If it is possible, please tell me the approach. 
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of properties added to the Config.groovy:

```
environments {
  development {
    tipline.email.address="joe@foo.us"
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
  }
  staging {
    tipline.email.address="mailinglist@foo.us"
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
  }
  production {
    tipline.email.address="mailinglist@foo.us"
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
    // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
  }
}
```

To access them in your code:

```
    println("Email :"+grailsApplication.config.tipline.email.address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties are properties =)

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File('test.properties')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
    properties.load(it)
}

def runtimeString = 'a'
assert properties."$runtimeString" == '1'
assert properties.b == '2'
```

Taken from [Get values from properties file using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871441/get-values-from-properties-file-using-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to inject parameters into the controller by using a [property override configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#propertyOverrideConfiguration):

```
// Config.groovy:

website.user = "me"

beans {
    '<replace by package>.WebsiteController' {
            userName = website.user
    }
}


// Controller:

class WebsiteController {
    String userName

    def show(){
        //.. use userName ..
    }
}
```

In this case you don't need `grailsApplication` and you don't hard code the configuration path in the Controller. Less dependencies make testing easier. :)