# How to read file using groovy and store its contents are variables?

Tags: java, groovy, readfile

I'm looking for groovy specific way to read file and store its content as different variables. Example of my properties file:

```
#Local credentials:
postgresql.url = xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
postgresql.username = xxxxxxx
postgresql.password = xxxxxxx
console.url = xxxxx.xxxx.xxx
```

At the moment I'm using this java code to read the file and use variables:

```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  InputStream input = null;

  try {
            input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            prop.load(input);
            this.postgresqlUser = prop.getProperty("postgresql.username")
            this.postgresqlPass = prop.getProperty("postgresql.password")
            this.postgresqlUrl = prop.getProperty("postgresql.url")
            this.consoleUrl = prop.getProperty("console.url")

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My colleague recommended to use groovy way to deal with this and mentioned streams but I can't seem to find much information about on how to store data in separate variables, what I know so far is that `def text = new FileInputStream("config.properties").getText("UTF-8")` could read whole file and store it in one variable, but not separate. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871441/get-values-from-properties-file-using-groovy

Comment: @tim thanks, solved my problem instead of all these try and catch now I can use `propertiesFile.withInputStream` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ConfigSlurper:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/10/groovy-goodness-using-configslurper.html

Comment: Agreed. ConfigSlurper is a much better option to using traditional Java properties files. Makes it a breeze.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to make your property file keys and class properties abide by a naming convention, then you can apply the property file values quite easily. Here's an example:

```
def config = '''
#Local credentials:
postgresql.url = xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
postgresql.username = xxxxxxx
postgresql.password = xxxxxxx
console.url = xxxxx.xxxx.xxx
'''

def props = new Properties().with {
    load(new StringBufferInputStream(config))
    delegate
}

class Foo {
    def postgresqlUsername
    def postgresqlPassword
    def postgresqlUrl
    def consoleUrl

    Foo(Properties props) {
        props.each { key, value ->
            def propertyName = key.replaceAll(/\../) { it[1].toUpperCase() }
            setProperty(propertyName, value)
        }
    }
}

def a = new Foo(props)

assert a.postgresqlUsername == 'xxxxxxx'
assert a.postgresqlPassword == 'xxxxxxx'
assert a.postgresqlUrl == 'xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
assert a.consoleUrl == 'xxxxx.xxxx.xxx'
```

In this example, the property keys are converted by dropping the '.' and capitalizing the following letter. So `postgresql.url` becomes `postgresqlUrl`. Then it's just a matter for iterating through the keys and calling `setProperty()` to apply the value.