# Where does groovy look for properties files by default?

Tags: netbeans, groovy, configuration, properties-file, idioms

For this Netbeans project:

```
.
├── build.xml
├── manifest.mf
├── nbproject
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── groovy-build.xml
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
└── src
    ├── Config1.groovy
    └── net
        └── bounceme
            └── mordor
                └── groovy
                    └── file_ops
                        └── NewGroovyScript.groovy

8 directories, 10 files
```

what would the standard location, or path, for `foo.properties` so that it [can be easily picked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871441/get-values-from-properties-file-using-groovy)?  in `src`?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in src in the same folder as NewGroovyScript.groovy?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to stick it in the same folder as your `NewGroovyScript.groovy` class file, then just do:

```
Properties p = NewGroovyScript.class.getResource('foo.properties').withInputStream { s ->
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(s)
    properties
}
```