# Is it possible to set sonar.sources in jenkins the same way it is set in gradle ?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, sonarqube

I have a gradle multi module project. I don't have a src directory in the root package, everything is in module.

I am using gradle sonar plugin in dev for deploying to sonar.

See the gradle sonar plugin [configuration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)

I use jenkins for deploying to prod sonar.

This is my **sonar-project.properties**

```
# Required metadata
sonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.service.consul
sonar.projectKey=com.domain.api
sonar.projectName=com.domain.api

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=.
sonar.inclusions=**/src/main/java/**/*.java
sonar.exclusions=**/src/main/test/**/*.java
sonar.test.exclusions=**/src/main/test/**/*.java

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

The problem I have is that gradle sonar plugin set `sonar.sources` dynamically.

I wasn't able to do this on jenkins with the plugin sonar.

Answer (score 1):

The [JENKINS SonarQube plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin), as [documented here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) "lets you centralize the configuration of SonarQube server connection details in Jenkins global configuration."

That means it will inject the environment variable `SONAR_HOST_URL` to your job (to be used in a mvn build step)

Nothing prevents you to write a groovy script which would set that same environment variable `SONAR_HOST_URL` to a value dynamically set (for instance, a [script using the EnvInject plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936515/6309)).

Comment: Ok. Appart that EnvInject isn't maintained anymore and have issues when installed with other plugins. How do you set in your `sonar-project.properties` your `sonar.sources` ? Otherwise, how can I know the value of sonar.sources for my project in gradle so I can use it on jenkins ?

Comment: @BigDong you have another approach based on ParametersAction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25796504/6309. The idea is not to set `sonar-project.properties` but to override some of its properties when the job is executed. Those properties can also be first loaded (by the same grrovy script): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20872275/6309. That way, you can load one originally used by gradle.