# passing variables beetwen groovy files

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, dsl

I'm managing many jobs in Jenkins by DSL plugin. That plugin is using .groovy definitions so I think even if someone doesn't use Jenkins but using groovy may be able to help.

Generally, I want to create an additional file, that may be a groovy file, JSON or YAML, whatever. It important is the possibility to connect that file with my .groovy file.

In that file, I'm defining variables(rather just strings) for example address IP or other stuff
eg.

```
ip_gitlab: 1.2.3.4
default_user: admin
```

In my groovy files, I want to be able to use these variables.

That approach is possible in groovy?

Comment: of course that is possible. For example there is http://groovy-lang.org/json.html.

Comment: If it's possible to define additional classpath in DSL plugin. then put into the folder that you will add to classpath groovy file(s) like `class GLOBAL{ def a=111; def b=222; }`. then in code you should be able to access it `GLOBAL.a`

Comment: @daggett I was trying as you wrote and always I have got error:
`org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$1@641eff69' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$1' to class 'javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent'`  This error occurs during processing your class GLOBAL

Comment: i forgot . for each defined variable there should be `static` prefix. `class GLOBAL{ static def a=111; static def b=222; }`. but error you have is strange. could you show the variable you've declared and how you use it in dsl.

Comment: 1. My configuration of the dsl https://postimg.cc/TLHK5k6h  2. error during dsl processing https://postimg.cc/21F37jDs

Comment: 3. structure of the DSL https://postimg.cc/BXfKTVF1 .  Jenkins is the newest -2.190.1, addon DSL also up-to-date.

Comment: @daggett do you have any idea?

Comment: @rafal1337, i never worked with this plugin, and according to the screenshot there is no additional classpath parameter. check documentation for `config*` methods and probably `JsonSlurper` could be a solution. check example here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL#4-adding-additional-jobs-to-the-dsl-script

Comment: The error means you have your class has to extend JobParent, as they have their own script loading infrastructure and that infrastructure expects only a JobParent, not an arbitrary class.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest use a [property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871441/get-values-from-properties-file-using-groovy) as @JBaruch wrote

```
ip_gitlab=1.2.3.4
default_user=admin
```

And load it

> ```
> Properties properties = new Properties()
> File propertiesFile = new File('test.properties')
> propertiesFile.withInputStream {
>     properties.load(it)
> }
> ```

Then you can use it, get ip for example:

```
def ipPropertyName= 'ip_gitlab'
properties."$ipPropertyName"
```

Comment: This is a minimally attributed copy from the other post; you'd at least want to follow the [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and name the author.

Comment: Unfornetly that doesn't work in Jenkins DSL, can't find the file with properties, but this file is the same folder... `FATAL: test.properties (No such file or directory) java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.properties (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @rafal1337 Did you try using partial/full path of file?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I was trying multiple path but without positive effect.

Comment: @rafal1337 try `readFile` https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/

Answer (score 2):

Make groovy file and define some general information and use `load`.

E.g., hello.conf (written by groovy)

```
build_name = 'hello'

build_config = [
    'git': 'your git repository',
    'build_job': ['bulid_a', 'build_b']
]
```

And use it by `load`

```
load 'hello.conf'

println(build_name)
for (job in build_config['build_job']) {
    build job: job
}
```

Comment: looks good but in DSL plugin in Jenkins doesn't work: `ERROR: (pipeline.groovy, line 1) No signature of method: pipeline.load() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [a_test.groovy]Possible solutions: job(java.lang.String), find(), folder(java.lang.String), job(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait()`

Answer (score 2):

if you want a Jenkins specific answer:
There's a [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) to jenkins.

You can store config/properties files via Managed files.
Go to Manage Jenkins>Managed files and and create a new file. It supports .groovy, .json, .xml and many others.

Once you have that, you can load the said file inside a job using the Provide Config file checkbox which will load the file into an env variable automatically.